# Wolfram Cloud memory limit exceeded with complex Lagrange multipliers

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I'm new to the forum and I have problems when I try to run this code. The computation exceeds the limit of my plan.

This is my code. What can I do?

```
clear[f,g]
f[k_,l_,m_,n_,o_]:=(k^0.05)(l^0.09)(m^0.08)(n^0.43)(o^0.35);
g[k_,l_,m_,n_,o_]:=116.7k+216.7l+183m+31n+833.3o-71500;
Solve[
  D[f[k,l,m,n,o] - lambda g[k,l,m,n,o], {{k,l,m,n,o,lambda}}] == 0, 
  {k,l,m,n,o}, lambda]
```

Comment: (1) The logarithm being monotonic, optimizing `f` is equivalent to optimizing `log(f)`. So use `PowerExpand[Log[f[k, l, m, n, o]]]`. (2) This might all work better with exact numbers. But if you take that log it is not likely to matter.

Comment: `clear` should be `Clear`. This doesn't resolve the problem, though.

Comment: The lambda in Solve[... , ... , lambda] specifies a domain like Reals or Complex. I think this hardly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) all of the constants

```
f[k_, l_, m_, n_, o_] = (k^0.05) (l^0.09) (m^0.08) (n^0.43) (o^0.35) // 
   Rationalize;
g[k_, l_, m_, n_, o_] = 
  116.7 k + 216.7 l + 183 m + 31 n + 833.3 o - 71500 // Rationalize;

eqns = Thread[
    D[f[k, l, m, n, o] - 
       lambda g[k, l, m, n, o], {{k, l, m, n, o, lambda}}] == 0] // Simplify;
```

Include `lambda` in the list of variables to be found and use the [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) option `Method -> Reduce`

```
(sol = Solve[eqns, {k, l, m, n, o, lambda}, Method -> Reduce] // 
    N) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {4.0572, {{k -> 30.6341, l -> 29.6954, m -> 31.2568, n -> 991.774, 
   o -> 30.0312, lambda -> 0.00189561}}} *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
And @@ (eqns /. sol[[1]])

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

`FindRoot` works well on this problem:

```
Clear[f, g]
f[k_, l_, m_, n_, o_] := (k^0.05) (l^0.09) (m^0.08) (n^0.43) (o^0.35);
g[k_, l_, m_, n_, o_] := 116.7 k + 216.7 l + 183 m + 31 n + 833.3 o - 71500;
FindRoot[D[f[k, l, m, n, o] - 
    lambda g[k, l, m, n, o], {{k, l, m, n, o, lambda}}], {#, 1} & /@ {k, l, m, n, o, 
    lambda}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.0331255, {k -> 30.6341, l -> 29.6954, m -> 31.2568, n -> 991.774, o -> 30.0312, 
  lambda -> 0.00189561}}
 *)
```